# typescript export type and module value

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I want to export a type with the same name as a value. Here's an example module:

```js
// foo.ts

export type Foo = string;

export function create(): Foo {
  // ...
}
```

What's the reason that this pattern works:

```js
// index.ts
import * as _Foo from "./foo";
export const Foo = _Foo;
export type Foo = _Foo.Foo;
```

But these patterns don't?

```js
// No compiler error but value is not exported
export type Foo = import("./foo").Foo;
export * as Foo from "./foo";

// Duplicate identifier error
import type { Foo } from "./foo";
import * as Foo from "./foo";
export { Foo };

// Individual declarations in merged declaration 'Foo' must be all exported or all local. [2395]
import * as Foo from "./foo";
export { Foo };
export type Foo = Foo.Foo;
```

Answer (score 4):

Type aliases [do not produce a value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts).

Let me explain what is going on in your examples

```
// Types (Foo) and values (create) are imported into a single variable
import * as _Foo from "./foo"; 

// The module is reexported with another name
export const Foo = _Foo;

// The type is reexported with another name
export type Foo = _Foo.Foo;
```

Compiled version does not contain a type of course

```
var _Foo = require("./foo");
exports.Foo = _Foo;
```

After that, if `Foo` is used as a type it is correctly resolved to `string`, but if `Foo` is used as a value it is an object with `create` field.

The fun fact is that you can use `typeof Foo` now and it will be `{ create: () => string }`

Moving forward, the following is pretty the same as previous but because the first import explicitly states it is a type it is possible to use the same name for the value export

```
export type Foo = import("./foo").Foo; // does not produce a variable
export * as Foo from "./foo"; // named value export
```

Compiles into

```
exports.Foo = require("./foo");
```

The next one is a bit tricky, to be honest, I don't know why it does not work. I guess it may be a bug since `import type` is a shiny new feature but I have not found it.

```
import type { Foo } from "./foo";
import * as Foo from "./foo";
export { Foo };
```

Locally defined type works:

```
type Foo = string;
import * as Foo from "./foo";
export { Foo };
```

And the last one, since `Foo` is declared in this import cannot be merged with it. You can take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36684) for details.

```
import * as Foo from "./foo";
export { Foo }; 
export type Foo = Foo.Foo; // <- local definition
```

It can be rewritten using a temporary identifier, just you did it in the first example: (it does not work, see update below)

```
import * as _Foo from './Foo'
export { _Foo as Foo }
export type Foo = _Foo.Foo
```

**Update**

The last listed snippet produces correct js output but throws an error when the export is used as a value:

```
import * as _Foo from './merged'
const x: Foo = '1234'; // Ok
const y = Foo.create(); // <- TS2693: 'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

It seems like a bug but I cannot find it posted

Comment: The JavaScript output is as expected, but I can't get the re-export workaround you mentioned working: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36684#issuecomment-610132392

Comment: regarding the `import type` problem, I just raised https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50880